# When is lagrange multiplier the best choice?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Let f(x,y) be a smooth function.

If i want to find the min and max of this function in the quarter disk constrained by x^2+y^2=1 in the first quadrant.

Can i then use lagrange multiplier to do this or is the best way to go to just search for stationary points and then check the boundery?

Comment: I find that using Lagrange multiplies is essentially always the best choice when it's doable. Is this too simplistic of an answer? Perhaps.

Comment: Usually Lagrange is used when there is a constraint on the variables, along with the objective function to be max/min-ed.

Comment: You have a circle, not a disk. If I remember correctly, Lagarange Multiplier only works on smooth regions; your region isn't smooth. You can just apply EVT to this region.

Answer (score 0):

Lagrange multipliers will work for "most" of the boundary if you take the boundary to be 3 pieces: $x = 0$, $y = 0$, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. But then you need to check the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$ separately because the min or max could happen at one of these points and you might not find it with Lagrange multipliers on the 3 boundaries.

Comment: How do i set up the equations in the way you are talking about, i mean in 3 pieces?

Comment: The 3 pieces are defined by the 3 separate equations, $x = 0, y = 0, x^2 + y^2 = 1$. You run Lagrange multipliers with each equation separately. Some of the critical points you find this way will be outside of your region, because you also have $1 \geq x,y \geq 0$ but that's ok.

Comment: Im sorry for being slow but im not really sure that i get it..

When i set it up for the circle i get

f_x = lambda*2x, 
f_y = lambda*2y, 
x^2+y^2 = 1, 

And then for the other two? If i add x = 0 and y = 0 i will just end up with the origin?